# how to bind observable collection Count value in textblock Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

How i can bind observable collection Count value in textblock in windows phone in listbox

```
  <Grid Margin="440,26,10,0"  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                            <Grid Height="25" MinWidth="25">
                                                <Grid.Background>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image}"  Stretch="Fill"/>
                                                </Grid.Background>
                                                <TextBlock Name="Message_Count" Text="{Binding CollectionCount}" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>

List<CountMsg> retrieved = dbConnCount.Table<CountMsg>().ToList<CountMsg>();
            dbCount = new ObservableCollection<CountMsg>(retrieved);
```

i want to bind dbCount.Count in textblock;

Comment: Define a read-only property that it's `getter` returns `dbCount.Count` and then bind your `textBlock.Text` to this property.

Comment: Bahman_Aries sir could you plz send more info or any example its urgent sir

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

MainWindow.cs:

```
    ObservableCollection<CountMsg> dbCount;

    public int CollectionCount
    {
        get
        {
            return dbCount.Count;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        List<CountMsg> retrieved = dbConnCount.Table<CountMsg>().ToList<CountMsg>();
        dbCount = new ObservableCollection<CountMsg>(retrieved);

    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow">
    ....
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CollectionCount}" ... />
    ....
</Window>
```

Comment: sir the code i have post i am getting dbCount.Count value but not able to display it?

Comment: This example works fine. You set white `Foreground` for your `TextBlock`. have you noticed that?